# Angular 7, Virtual Scroll. Can't set scrollTop in max

Tags: angular, angular7

Try to use Virtual Scroll for my chat. Work fine but I have a problem. When data loaded I set scrollTop in max to move to end the chat. But as a result, I am not at the end but almost in end (about 500px higher than bottom). Maybe some ideas on how to fix it?

I use directive `CdkScrollable` from `'@angular/cdk/scrolling'`.

Use it in a component like this:

```
@ViewChildren(CdkScrollable) cdkScrollable;

scrollToEnd() {    
    this.cdkScrollable.first.scrollTo({bottom: 0});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand what is a problem. I use `FixedSizeVirtualScrollStrategy` but I don't have a common size for elements.